# Selenium driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() doesn't work when using Browser options

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I have noticed that when using browser Options in selenium, `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` doesn't work.
Not sure why but here is a snippet of the code.

```
var profile = new firefox.Profile('./fProfile');
profile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart",true);
var fOptions = new firefox.Options();
fOptions.setProfile(profile); 

var driver = new Builder()
    .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'firefox'})
    .setFirefoxOptions(fOptions)    
    .build();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

In the above driver setup the 
`driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` doesn't work
and  `driver.manage().getCookies().then((cookies)=>{console.log(cookies)})` returns an **empty** array

However when using this to create the driver the above functions work.

```
driver= new Builder()
    .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'firefox'})    
    .build();
```

Though I cant use the above code since *I **require** the use of a firefox profile.*

Platform : Node.Js Selenium using geckodriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out **turning off** private browsing did the trick.Removing the line works too.

```
profile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart",false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I'd start working backwards.

You know that removing `.setFirefoxOptions(fOptions)` fixes the issue, but options include manually setting a preference and loading a pre-configured profile.

- Try using a blank profile and see what happens.
- Try not turning on private browsing and see what happens.

You should whittle down where the problem is coming from and you can get a better answer.